# @EnableConfigurationProperties does not work with yaml format but works with the dot notation

Tags: java, spring, properties

I'm trying to test a simple property binding from my application.yml file to a POJO class. I can get my unit test to print out the property value when I have the property set using dot notation but when I change the same property to a .yml representation my unit test prints out a null. Am I missing something here?

```
# this works
blah.resourcePrefix=blah
```

```
# this does not work
blah:
  resourcePrefix: blah
```

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "blah")
public class JustTesting {

    private String resourcePrefix;

    public String getResourcePrefix() {
        return resourcePrefix;
    }
    public void setResourcePrefix(String resourcePrefix) {
        this.resourcePrefix = resourcePrefix;
    }
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = JustTesting.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class PropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    JustTesting justTesting;

    @Test
    public void testProperties(){        
        System.out.println(justTesting.getResourcePrefix());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further digging, surprisingly it turns out that @TestPropertySource does not support .yml files. Baeldung has a nice article that describes how to add that functionality.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource

I went a slightly different route that also ended up working for me and updated my unit test annotations like so. This way my application.yml file got picked up without me having to specify it's location.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = JustTesting.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = JustTesting.class)
public class PropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    JustTesting justTesting;

    @Test
    public void testProperties(){        
        System.out.println(justTesting.getResourcePrefix());        
    }
}
```